# Apache NiFi: InferAvroSchema infers signed values as string

Tags: hive, avro, apache-nifi, kite-sdk

I'm setting up a pipeline in NiFi where I get JSON records which I then use to make a request to an API. The response I get would have both numeric and textual data. I then have to write this data to Hive. I use `InferAvroSchema` to infer the schema. Some numeric values are signed values like `-2.46,-0.1` While inferring the type, the processor considers them as `string` instead of `double` or `float` or `decimal` type.

I know we can hard code our AVRO schema in the processors but I thought making it more dynamic by utilizing the `InferAvroSchema` would be even better. Is there any other way we can overcome/resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InferAvroSchema is good for guessing an initial schema, but once you need something more specific it is better to remove InferAvroSchema and provide the exact schema you need.

Comment: Okay. However, it can be done, right? They are using Kite SDK. It's just a fewer lines of code that scans the field values and if the values are signed, and are numeric, it can be inferred as double/decimal, else if it has alphabets, infer it as string. Or is it much more complex than that?